# Configuring CSRF Allowed Sites in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, csrf, http-status-code-403, sap-commerce-cloud, csrf-protection

I have my e-commerce website and dealing with a 3rd party payment vendor integration. I send them a URL and they're returning a POST request to it. The problem is I'm receiving 403-bad or Missing CSRF Token error. 
The incoming request is as follows:

```
Request URL:https://mavi.local:9002/checkout/callback/secure3d?CSRFToken=425cc3ee-df74-482a-955b-c7836abff410&responseCode=0000&token=D7ED3EBA21864253AD7AA33AABB492C7FA90DDEBD7AD448D1210EF85814E077505BC8E58E1F29AC2153E600678E6545A2D87FAACF516AC3249F7D8572EA767835C89F1E370C01532F0DCCABF8ACCC7F215AE838E9B917204F1C362140E6F5E87
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9002
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

And the initiator is:

```
test.masterpassturkiye.com/RedirectServer/MMIUIMasterPass_V2/s3d/bank/success?RRN=500007047967:7
```

I'm trying to add this url as allowed Cross Origin request in my Spring configuration. 
I have tried 2 options.

1. Updating csrf.allowed.url.patterns setting in project.properties as follows:

   csrf.allowed.url.patterns=/.*callback|.*masterpass|[^/]+(/[^?]*)+(sop/response)$,/[^/]+(/[^?]*)+(merchant_callback)$,/[^/]+(/[^?]*)+(hop/response)$,/[^/]+(/[^?]*)+(language)$,/[^/]+(/[^?]*)+(currency)$

This regex mathces with the url but not the whole URL, I think it might be a problem, yet I'm not sure.

2. Inserted below item into my spring-mvc-config.xml

```xml
<util:list id="csrfAllowedUrlPatternsList" value-type="java.lang.String" >
        <value>.*masterpass</value>
    </util:list>
```

I adopted this solution from this [blog post](https://hybrisdiary.com/2016/01/19/error-submitting-a-from-due-to-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf/)

Yet the problem with the 403 error still continues. What might be the possible problem with my configurations? Any help or idea will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your value in ***spring-mvc-config.xml*** is wrong.

Please try with **/checkout/callback/secure3d** since this is the Hybris URL which handles the POST request and which should not ask for a CSRF token.
To make everything more clear, your ***spring-mvc-config.xml*** should contain this:

```
<util:list id="csrfAllowedUrlPatternsList" value-type="java.lang.String" >
    <value>/checkout/callback/secure3d</value>
</util:list>
```

I believe that this is valid for the **csrf.allowed.url.patterns** as well.
The regex should apply to the call back URL (i.e **/checkout/callback/secure3d**) instead of the initiator.